# How do I catch a java.sql.sqlexception within a Ruby program?

Tags: java, sql, ruby, jruby

I am sure I am doing something stupid here. I am using Ruby 1.9.2-p312, jruby 1.6.8 with the --1.9 option set as default. This is my first attempt at trying to rescue an SQLException. I purposely fail this code by unplugging the ethernet connection.

```
require 'java'
require 'lib/jt400-6.1'
require 'date'
require 'bigdecimal'

java_import 'com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver'def initialize(parms={})

class DB
  def initialize(parms = {})
    begin
      @connection ||= java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection "jdbc:as400://System/",parms[:user], parms[:pass]
    rescue java.sql.SQLException
      puts "Error connecting to iSeries. Error code: #{java.sql.SQLException.getErrorCode()}
                SQL State: #{java.sql.SQLException.getSQLState()}."
    end
  end
end
```

This produces the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `getErrorCode' for Java::JavaSql::SQLException:Class:
/home/nick/Projects/OrderBridge/app/db.rb:17:in `initialize'
/home/nick/Projects/OrderBridge/app/order-processor.rb:208:in `prepare'
/home/nick/Projects/OrderBridge/app/orderbridge.rb:43:in `POST /advanced'
org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:117:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `compile!'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:258:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:785:in `route!'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:801:in `route_eval'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:785:in `route!'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:822:in `process_route'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1226:in `catch'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:820:in `process_route'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:784:in `route!'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1620:in `each'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:783:in `route!'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:886:in `dispatch!'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:719:in `call!'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `invoke'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1226:in `catch'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `invoke'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:719:in `call!'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:705:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:17:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-protection-1.2.0/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:48:in `_call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lint.rb:36:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/chunked.rb:43:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/home/nick/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/nick/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.9/webrick/server.rb:183:in `start_thread'
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to catch the exception into a variable.

```
class DB
  def initialize(parms = {})
    begin
      @connection ||= java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection "jdbc:as400://System/",parms[:user], parms[:pass]
    rescue java.sql.SQLException => e
      puts "Error connecting to iSeries. Error code: #{e.getErrorCode()}
                SQL State: #{e.getSQLState()}."
    end
  end
end
```

This way you are not calling `.getErrorCode()` on the exception's class but rather the instance of the exception.

[Dealing with exceptions in jRuby](http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/05/24/dealing-with-java-exceptions-in-jruby/)

Comment: Thank you!. This works when I leave out the SQLException method but still fails otherwise with: undefined method `getErrorCode' for #<NativeException:0x384e57ba>

Comment: After searching my brain and Google, I have two suggestions. Since you converted `DriverManager.getConnection()` to `DriverManager.get_connection`, what if you tried `e.get_error_code`? Another option is to find an alternative method for [NativeException](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/NativeException.html) that might work. I code in MRI Ruby and I usually have to parse the `e.message` with some regex to get the database's error code.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply..I went back to try and use get_error_code but alas it is undefined as well. I moved on by not calling those methods at all and printing the object itself (#{e}). Not the greatest but at least it gives me info on the failure instead of failing on some nil object later.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the puts statement.  You are referring to the exception class not the object, try

```
rescue java.sql.SQLException => e
  puts "Error connecting to iSeries. Error code: #{e.getErrorCode()}
            SQL State: #{e.getSQLState()}."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this similar issue and thought of sharing my solution which is to make use of "message" and "wrapped_exception.error_code" which is available as well if needed.

```
class DB
  def initialize(parms = {})
    begin
      @connection ||= java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection "jdbc:as400://System/",parms[:user], parms[:pass]
    rescue java.sql.SQLException => e
      puts "Error message: #{e.message}
                Msg: #{e.wrapped_exception.error_code}."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to edit your answer to include some explanation, rather than simply posting a block of code.